# NSArrayM was mutated while being enumerated - adding objects, not removing

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I tried looking over all these problems on StackOverflow and couldn't find anything that helped me. I can't even replicate it myself, i got this from actual users through iTunes Connect. This are the crash logs on Xcode:

[image]

This is my full serializedLocations method that is crashing, nothing stripped from it:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)serializedLocations:(NSArray *)locations withTimestamp:(NSInteger)timestamp{
    NSMutableArray *serializedLocations = [NSMutableArray new];

    if(locations){
        for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
            NSInteger locationTimeInterval = floor([location.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000);
            NSInteger t = locationTimeInterval - timestamp;
            NSMutableDictionary *serializedLocation = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            serializedLocation[@"x"] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude];
            serializedLocation[@"y"] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude];
            serializedLocation[@"a"] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.horizontalAccuracy];
            serializedLocation[@"v"] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.speed];
            serializedLocation[@"o"] = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.course];
            serializedLocation[@"t"] = [NSNumber numberWithLong:t];
            [serializedLocations addObject:serializedLocation];
        }
    }
    return serializedLocations;
}
```

I can't seem to find the flaw.

- I'm creating a temp new array.
- I don't change the array that I'm enumerating.
- I'm adding new objects to the temp array.
- I'm returning that new temp array

EDIT:

The parent that gets all the other methods going is called like this:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [ApiClient insertEvent:event withLocations:locations];
    });
```

Comment: But it's happening on a background thread? What if `locations` is itself mutable? And what if it is being mutated by something else while this background thread is holding a reference to it? I don't see you doing anything here to make this code thread-safe.

Comment: Yes, it's happening on a background thread. Care to share how I can make this piece of code thread-safe?

Comment: Should I just create a copy of locations and enumerate that copy instead?

Comment: "Sharing" is the whole problem. What you want to do is _not_ share `locations`. At the very least, why not take a deep copy of it, first thing? — Ooooh, I see that while I was typing, you thought of that! :)

Comment: :D Thanks @matt I'll go ahead and do it myself now. If you want to make a proper answer, I'd be happy to select it. Thanks!

Comment: @matt Is `NSArray *locationsCopy = [NSArray arrayWithArray:locations];` considered a "deep copy"?

Comment: It isn't deep, but I think in this case it would be sufficient because a CLLocation is not mutable. If this were an array of MyWidget objects you'd need to copy those as well, lest one of them be mutated behind your back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `locations`, although typed here as an NSArray, is in fact an NSMutableArray — and that *this* is the array that is being mutated while you are enumerating it. If you are going to run this code on a background thread, you need to ensure that `locations` is not being mutated "behind your back". An easy way to do that would be to make a deep copy of `locations` at the call site and pass *that* rather than the mutable array. (Note that it is not sufficient to make the deep copy here in `serializedLocations:withTimestamp:`, as `locations` could be mutated *during the copy*.)

Comment: Ohh I was about to do just that. Didn't realize that it could be mutated "during the copy". I know this is off topic of this question, but is there a way to actually test this?

Comment: We're talking about multithreading here! To assume that a thing cannot happen is really a bad idea. Always assume the worst. After all, failure to do that is how you got into this mess; you are wantonly sharing out a mutable object across threads. This was bad design from the get-go; you're just lucky the problem arose in such clear form and that it was even possible to _guess_ the cause. More usually, threading issues bite you much later than the actual mistake. I suggest you go back over all your code immediately and look for other multithreading places.